# Does it suck or not - Simple DAL with caching using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, caching, linq-to-sql, enterprise-library

I created a simple Caching Data Access Layer that has caching using the Enterprise Library Caching Application Block and also makes use of SQL Query Notification - therefore not supporting any queries which are not valid for query notification.

Background: This was put in place after the application was developed in order to lighten the load on the database and speed up the application. The main use of this DAL is for pulling data that is not expected to change very often such as data in Look Up Tables (presented in drop downs on the UI, etc).

It is mainly used like the following example:

```
var cachingDal = new CachingDataAccessLayer();
var productTypes = cachingDal.LoadData<ProductType>();
```

Where ProductType is a Linq to SQL table. I am curious to see what people think of the implementation I came up with and if it is horrible or amazing.

Here's the code. Looking for any suggestions, criticisms, etc etc. Keep in mind I didn't choose the technology and am building on top of an existing system so switching data access stories is not really my call.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;
using MyDatabase;

public class CachingDataAccessLayer
{
    #region Cache Keys
    private const string CacheManagerName = "CachingDataAccessLayer";
    #endregion

    #region Database
    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiate new MyDataContext
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private MyDataContext DatabaseConnection()
    {
        // instantiate database connection
        var database = new MyDataContext(Constants.DatabaseConnectionString);

        // set transaction isolation level to read committed
        database.ExecuteQuery(typeof(string), "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED");

        return database;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Generic Data Access with Caching
    /// <summary>
    /// Calls .Exists on list using predicate and if it evaluates to false, adds records to list using predicate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">Database table</typeparam>
    /// <param name="list">List to add records to</param>
    /// <param name="predicate">The delagate that defines the conditions of elements to search for.</param>
    public void AddRecordsIfNeeded<TEntity>(ref List<TEntity> list, Predicate<TEntity> predicate) where TEntity : class
    {
        // check if items are in list based on predicate and if not, add them to the list
        if (!list.Exists(predicate))
        {
            list.AddRange(LoadData<TEntity>(predicate.Invoke));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve all records of type TEntity from the cache if available with filter Active = true (if Active property exists).<br/>
    /// If data is not available in cache go directly to the database.<br/>
    /// In addition, sets up query notification and refreshes cache on database change.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">Database table to retrieve.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>returns List of TEntity</returns>
    public List<TEntity> LoadData<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        // default filter is no filter
        Func<TEntity, bool> predicate = delegate { return true; };

        // check for active property
        var activeProperty = typeof (TEntity).GetProperty("Active");

        // if active property exists and is a boolean, set predicate to filter Active == true
        if (activeProperty != null)
            if (activeProperty.PropertyType.FullName == typeof (bool).FullName)
                predicate = (x => (bool) activeProperty.GetValue(x, null));

        // load data & return
        return LoadData(predicate);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve all records of type TEntity from the cache if available.<br/>
    /// If data is not available in cache go directly to the database.<br/>
    /// In addition, sets up query notification and refreshes cache on database change.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">Database table to retrieve.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="predicate">A function to test each element for a condition.</param>
    /// <returns>returns List of TEntity</returns>
    public List<TEntity> LoadData<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate) where TEntity : class
    {
        // default is to not refresh cache
        return LoadData(predicate, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve all records of type TEntity from the cache if available.<br/>
    /// If data is not available in cache or refreshCache is set to true go directly to the database.<br/>
    /// In addition, sets up query notification and refreshes cache on database change.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">Database table to retrieve.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="predicate">A function to test each element for a condition.</param>
    /// <param name="refreshCache">If true, ignore cache and go directly to the database and update cache.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<TEntity> LoadData<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate, bool refreshCache) where TEntity : class
    {
        // instantiate database connection
        using (var database = DatabaseConnection())
        {
            // instantiate the cache
            var cache = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager(CacheManagerName);

            // get cache key name
            var cacheKey = typeof(TEntity).Name;

            // if the value is in the cache, return it
            if (cache.Contains(cacheKey) && !refreshCache)
                // get data from cache, filter it and return results
                return (cache.GetData(cacheKey) as List<TEntity>).Where(predicate).ToList();

            // retrieve the data from the database
            var data = from x in database.GetTable<TEntity>()
                       select x;

            // if value is in cache, remove it
            if (cache.Contains(cacheKey))
                cache.Remove(cacheKey);

            // add unfiltered results to cache
            cache.Add(cacheKey, data.ToList());

            Logger.Write(string.Format("Added {0} to cache {1} with key '{2}'", typeof(TEntity).Name, CacheManagerName, cacheKey));

            // set up query notification
            SetUpQueryNotification<TEntity>();

            // return filtered results
            return data.Where(predicate).ToList();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Query Notification
    public void SetUpQueryNotification<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        // get database connection
        var database = DatabaseConnection();

        // set up query notification
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Constants.DatabaseConnectionString))
        {
            // linq query
            var query = from t in database.GetTable<TEntity>()
                        select t;

            var command = database.GetCommand(query);

            // create sql command
            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(command.CommandText, sqlConnection))
            {
                // get query parameters
                var sqlCmdParameters = command.Parameters;

                // add query parameters to dependency query
                foreach (SqlParameter parameter in sqlCmdParameters)
                {
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parameter.ParameterName, parameter.SqlValue));
                }

                // create sql dependency
                var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(sqlCommand);

                // set up query notification
                sqlDependency.OnChange += sqlDependency_OnChange<TEntity>;

                // open connection to database
                sqlConnection.Open();

                // need to execute query to make query notification work
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        Logger.Write(string.Format("Query notification set up for {0}", typeof(TEntity).Name));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls LoadData of type TEntity with refreshCache param set to true.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">Database table to refresh.</typeparam>
    void RefreshCache<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        // refresh cache
        LoadData<TEntity>(delegate { return true; }, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Refreshes data in cache for type TEntity if type is Delete, Insert or Update.<br/>
    /// Also re-sets up query notification since query notification only fires once.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">Database table</typeparam>
    void sqlDependency_OnChange<TEntity>(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e) where TEntity : class
    {
        var sqlDependency = sender as SqlDependency;

        // this should never happen
        if (sqlDependency == null)
            return;

        // query notification only happens once, so remove it, it will be set up again in LoadData
        sqlDependency.OnChange -= sqlDependency_OnChange<TEntity>;

        // if the data is changed (delete, insert, update), refresh cache & set up query notification
        //  otherwise, just set up query notification
        if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Delete || e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Insert || e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Update)
        {
            // refresh cache & set up query notification
            Logger.Write(string.Format("sqlDependency_OnChange (Info: {0}, Source: {1}, Type: {2}). Refreshing cache for {3}", e.Info, e.Source, e.Type, typeof(TEntity).Name));
            RefreshCache<TEntity>();
        }
        else
        {
            // set up query notification
            SetUpQueryNotification<TEntity>();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data isn't expected to change very much and it's used for the UI such as for drop-downs etc., why not cache the data on client's machine? We did this for an application we built a while back. We cached almost all of our "look-up" type data in files on the client machine and then built a mechanism to invalidate the data when it was modified in the database. This was very fast and worked well for us.

BTW, are you aware that L2S does it's own caching?

Comment: Caching on the client side is probably a good option however we needed to implement something as quickly as possible so we went with a server side solution (I probably should have mentioned above that this is a web app running under webforms, though you seem to have picked up on that).
I was aware that L2S does its own caching but I was under the impression this is only for a single row result set and not a result set having multiple rows?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd suggest using the Repository pattern, where you have an IRepository.

Then, in real terms you could use an IoC container to provide your app with a CacheRepository for some static types that uses the caching system in the first instance and either automatically delegates on to a LinqToSqlRepository where data isn't found, or returns null and allows you to deal with populating the cache yourself.

Comment: Yes, the Repository pattern might be a better way to do the data access story. However L2S doesn't really easily work well with the Repository pattern and we needed to plug in something to the existing system quickly and easily, instead of rewriting everything.

Comment: Actually L2S works very well with the repo pattern.  If you look at DataContext.GetTable<TEntity>(), and connect it all together with an IoC container it can be quite good.

Comment: I'm using DataContext.GetTable<TEntity>() above to pull in the data. Maybe I'm just an idiot and I don't get it but can you point me towards something that explains why/how that makes the repository pattern easier? Again this was for an existing system where we wanted to do as little rewrite as possible and they were already binding directly against the L2S objects and did not have any domain objects or DTOs.